# AWS CodePipeline - CodeBuild to read only the changed files from source output artifacts

Tags: github, yaml, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

How to get the list of changed files from AWS CodePipeline's GitHub source? After a change is pushed into this GitHub branch, I want to check if there are changes in a specific folder path. If yes, CodeBuild should execute a set of commands, otherwise no.